# Liferay custom logic

Tags: hook, liferay

I know that I can extend existing functionality by creating a hook . But what if I need to create brand new custom *Utils class and include this class in the Liferay core.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom services using Liferay's service builder in a hook.

After generating the service. You will **move** the *service.jar that is generated in lib directory of your hook to [Server]/lib/ext folder (global path) and then deploy the hook.

This way the interface to access the service (*ServiceUtil & *LocalServiceUtil classes) will be available to all the portlets and hooks (i.e. liferay's core which you might override) and the implementation (i.e. your own logic) for the service will be in the hook.

Comment: Make sure you delete the jar from your hook/lib when you deploy. The service.jar should only be at one place that is server/lib/ext